# BC30560: '_global_asax' is ambiguous in the namespace 'ASP'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, iis-express

Good afternoon ,

Right now I'm working in a software developed by another programmer who it's no longer part of the project anymore, he send the complete source code of the project.

The thing is, that when debug on my local machine it throws BC30560: '_global_asax' is ambiguous in the namespace  'ASP'.

I already tried removing the bin and rebuilt

````
Línea 76:         
Línea 77:         Protected ReadOnly Property ApplicationInstance() As ASP._global_asax
Línea 78:             Get
Línea 79:                 Return CType(Me.Context.ApplicationInstance,ASP._global_asax)```
````

Comment: Is your problem only on iis? Does it work fine locally?

Comment: No, actually i had the problem on the local machine. The thing was that a I take all the dll references from the server where the program is running, and added to my project, but i also add as reference the build of the project, so when i was trying to builded on my local, it generates the dll of the project again.